# Visual Studio 2017 profiler results

Tags: visual-studio, profiling

I tried to profile a small C++ program and I noted that Debug configuration has a much more thorough results, i.e many more functions are displayed, with respect to the one of the Release configuration.

The question is: how can I get similar information without the overhead of a Debug build that is not only much slower but probably less significant?